# Magento 2.4.5 AbstractHelper' is not marked as an API

Tags: magento2

Extended class '\Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper' is not marked as an API

Inspection info:
The extended class is not marked as an API.

---

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;


class Customer extends AbstractHelper
{
...
```

Answer (score 0):

**Change**
Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
**to**
Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;

Example:

---

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
namespace Vendor\Module\Helper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;

class Customer
{
    protected $scopeConfigInterface;
    
    public function __construct(
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    ) {
        $this->scopeConfigInterface = $scopeConfig;
    }
    
    public function getData(): string
    {
        return   $this->scopeConfigInterface->getValue('web/secure/base_url')
    }
}
```